# Decomposition of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

It is a very simple question but I'm stuck in decomposing this: $x^3+2x^2-2$. I can't find the $x-c$ (Ruffini's rule) form that can enable me to decompose it. Is it possible to decompose? 
If I can solve it, I will be able to resolve an entire math problem!. It is an elementary question I know but I can't find a way to continue after several attemps. Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible to decompose it because it has degree $3$, but the decomposition is awful. If this comes up in an exercise, surely you're not meant to decompose it.

Comment: Probably! But I'm curious to find out how it have to be decomposed and however after I decompose it, I'm sure that I can solve the exercise ;-)

Comment: [Enjoy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B2x%5E2-2).

Comment: And, what is the exercise you have mentioned ?

Comment: calculus of a limit, just solved

Comment: There probably are easier ways.

Comment: I will retry finding easier ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Eisenstein, the polynomial $x^3 + 2x^2-2$ is $\mathbb Q$-irreducible, so there is no *rational* number $c$ such that $x-c$ divides your polynomial. It does have a *real* root $c$, though, which is easiest to find by various approximative processes.